# Excel Formula to define VB action - Please help refresh after cell changes value

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a label printing app in excel. The user will pick the product from a dropdown menu which in turn will lookup values to fill Cells A1, B1 and C1 (either X or 0)

X means to show a diamond shape, 0 to hide it.

if I change the value manually, the diamond appears/disapears. If I use the dropdown menu, the formula changes values of cells A1, B1 an C1, but VB ignores the change. Any ideas? thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then _
    Me.Shapes("Diamond 1").Visible = (Cells(1, 1).Value = "x")

If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then _
    Me.Shapes("Diamond 2").Visible = (Cells(1, 2).Value = "x")

If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 3 Then _
    Me.Shapes("Diamond 3").Visible = (Cells(1, 3).Value = "x")

End Sub
```

Comment: is the input `x` or `X`? I noticed you put `X` in your question but `x` in your code.

Comment: The change event is not triggered by formulas. There is a calculate event.

Comment: right. x. after the formula updates the cell value, it does not run the VB, if I click the cell and then click enter, VB runs

Comment: You need to use `Worksheet_Calculate`, not `Worksheet_Change`. The change event isn't triggered when formulas recalculate.

Comment: This completely solved my problem. Thank you